# free energy of variational autoencoder

Tags: restricted-boltzmann-machine, variational-bayes

There is a conception of free energy related to restricted boltzmann machine(RBM). Since variational autoencoder(VAE) is an alternative to RBM for autoencoding, is there a counterpart definition of free energy related to VAE?